# android: put login activity on top of the stack on each app start

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a LoginActivity, that is started on the first app start. In The Manifest I defined for LoginActivity

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

So, if i close the app while any other Activity is active (e.g. MyActivity) and open it again, the last active activity MyActivity is shown.

Is it possible to somehow overlay the LoginActivity on top of the stack on each app start? And if the LoginActivity will finish, the old activity stack will be used?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your MyActivity to be your launcher activity. In the OnCreate method, you can check if the user is logged, and, if not, you can start the login activity.
In your Manifest, define your login as a child of de MyActivity as

> android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"

So, when the user finish the login activity, he will be redirected to the previous activity.

Many apps uses SharedPreferences to save the state of the user, and determine if he is logged or not.

Comment: This is what I've done in one of my projects. I think starting the LoginActivity before the MainActivity is bad practice(if you don't have to login every time). Think about how often each case happens. Preferably the user will see the LoginActivty once so there is no need to start it every time and redirect to the MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

to make that, when navigating from one activity to another, make the **intent** to the new activity as a `NEW_TASK`:

```
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), New_Activity.class); //replace v.getContext with getApplicationContext() if redirecting is not a result of pressing some Button
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then, on each activity override the `onRestart()` method with the following:

```
@Override
public void onRestart() {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login_Activity.class); // be aware here, we navigate to Login activity without closing the old one
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```